# Passing variable from BackgroundTask to Tab

Tags: android, android-activity, background-task

Im sending data to background task to be processed but want to get the data back into tab1. This has got me flummoxed.

This is created from my activity

```
BackgroundTask backgroundTaskLogin = new BackgroundTask(Tab1Activity.this);    
backgroundTaskLogin.execute(task,username,password);
```

I can see the data I want in backgroundtask

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
}
```

But cant get it back into my tab activity.. Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Interface which returns the result to the activity back.

```
/*Create an interface*/
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted(Integer result);
}

/*Assign the values to the callback functions in AsyncTask*/
public class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    private static int counter;
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;

    public PerformTask(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
        this.listener = listener; //Initialising listener
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    listener.onTaskCompleted(result); //Assigning values to the callback function
    }     
}

/*Implement the Interface in you activity*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTaskCompleted {
   @Override
   public void onTaskCompleted(Integer result) {
        // The result contains the data you need
   }
}
```

Comment: Thought that was the answer - but just before I was about to jump and sing-- this

01-26 14:02:22.823: E/AndroidRuntime(646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main